# Class decorator to apply method decorator on all inherited class method

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

I have several classes that inherit the same class. What I want is to have a class decorator on the base class who add an other decorator on all method of all inherited classes.

Is it possible ? Is it a good pratice ?